# How do I point my SQL Server VM to my SCCM Server VM?

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, sql, sccm, vmware-server

WMI Provider Error: Access is denied. [0x80070005]

I cannot connect the SQL Server to the SCCM Server with two seperate VM's.

I have two VM's on my ESXI Host. I am trying to point one VM to another. One VM has SQL Server and the other VM has SCCM Server. I want the SCCM Server connected to the SQL Server. However, when I sign into the SQL Server connected to the domain and put in the SCCM admin account, it gives me this error:

WMI Provider Error: Access is denied. [0x80070005]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need go into the sql server management studio and assign sql permissions.
I would recommend to create an ad group for the accounts that need sql server admin permissions and then into the sql server management studio and adjust the security based on your requirements

Here is how

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Connect to the SQL Server
   instance. Navigate to "Security" > "Logins" in the Object Explorer.
2. Right-click on "Logins" and choose "New Login..."
3. Select "Windows authentication" and click "Search..."
4. Choose the AD group and click "OK."
5. Click "OK" to create the login.
6. In the Object Explorer, go to "Security" > "Logins." Right-click on
   the AD group login you just created and choose "Properties."
7. Under the "Server Roles" tab, assign the necessary server roles like
   'sysadmin' if you want to grant full administrative permissions.

Please check the SCCM docs what kind of sql permissions sccm needs an also apply least privilege with sql server security